# How to add a regex to search result in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following ES json objects in the ES

```
{
  "attachments": "<html><body><image src=2016_10_01_10_image.jpg/><image src=2016_10_01_10_image1.jpg><body/><html/>"
  ,"Sent": true
  ,"status":complete
}
```

I want a report

```
status:complete
date: 2016_10_01 count: 15
date: 2016_10_02 count: 14

status: flagged
date: 2016_10_01 count: 150
date: 2016_10_03 count: 2
```

I tried to use regex, but I don't know how to display the matches of the regex (the date)

what i have now is a 1st grader solution which i hate: i need to run this query 30 times, for each date :(

```
GET index/_search
{
    "size": 0, 
  "query": {
  "bool": {
      "must": [
         {
         "regexp": {
           "_attachments": ".*(2016_10_27).*"
       }

         },
          {"constant_score": {
           "filter":{
             "term":  {"Sent": true}
                    }
                             }
         }
      ]
  }

  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_toSent": {
     "terms" : {  "field": "Sent"}
   ,
   "aggs": {
            "group_by_status": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "status"
              }
            }
          }
       }
    }
  }
```